# Enhanced hybrid oil bug?

Tags: the-witcher-3

So I've found the manuscript of Enhanced hybrid oil, and already got the basic hybrid oil. But one of the ingredients needed to make the enhanced version of the oil is the enhanced hybrid oil itself... Anyone having the same issue?? or any trick to solve this one?

Comment: I've not had this problem, can you add a screenshot of the Alchemy window to your question please.

Comment: Are you sure you actually crafted the basic hybrid oil and they are asking for that? (I have to ask..)  
It would explain the missing ingredient as I'm not sure enhanced oils requiring the same enhanced oil is a known bug.

Comment: Are you certain you don't have the _Superior_ hybrid oil recipe? That would correctly display Enhanced hybrid oil as a ingredient