# Missing an ingredient for Enhanced Hybrid Oil

Tags: the-witcher-3

I saw someone had a similar problem, when I go to my alchemy menu and try to make Enhanced Hybrid Oil it says I am missing an ingredient. It shows the missing ingredient as Enhanced Hybrid Oil.
I checked to make sure it wasn't the Superior Hybrid Oil manuscript. I also restarted the application, that did not help. I also restarted the game entirely with a new profile and still had this issue.

If anyone knows how to fix this, please tell me!

Comment: [The related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228311). From the comments there - "_Are you certain you don't have the 'Superior' hybrid oil recipe?_"

Comment: Also from the comments on the related question, pertinent here too: "_can you add a screenshot of the Alchemy window to your question please_"